# Difference between css path and css selector in selenium webdriver firefox

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Problem is I want to locate many elements which share same css path but when I use

`elements= webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector("")`

This only works if I open inspect element.

However when running the code without opening inspect element I got
`elements=[ ]`

"nothing found"

I use **css path** because it's the only Mutual thing between the elements I want to locate.

[image: CSS Path]

Answer (score 2):

as i have tested, the css path is the "full" path trough the DOM tree to the element you wish to locate. 
Starting from html tag to (n) item.

That include each element in the tree until you reach the focused element.
Example:

```
html.wf-nunitosans-n4-active.wf-active body#gsr.hp.vasq.big div#viewport.ctr-p div#searchform.jhp.big form#tsf.tsf.nj div div.A8SBwf div.FPdoLc.tfB0Bf center input.gNO89b
```

CSS selector is the shortest path using css locators and axes to the focused item.

Example:

```
.FPdoLc > center:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I use css path because it's the only Mutual thing between the elements i want to locate, When i use css selectors it locate only on element

Comment: i would suggest to stick to css selectors, coz one change in dom tree and your css "path" will be invalid.